# How do I rename duplicates in MySQL using PHP or just a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rename

trying to rename duplicates in MySQL database so far using that code but this only adding 1 at the end of name. So if I have

```
    UPDATE phpfox_photo n 
  JOIN (SELECT title_url, MIN(photo_id) min_id FROM phpfox_photo GROUP BY title_url HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) d
    ON n.title_url = d.title_url AND n.photo_id <> d.min_id
SET n.title_url = CONCAT(n.title_url, '1'); 


Anna
Anna
Anna
```

Result is

```
Anna
Anna1
Anna11
```

When I got 200 Annas result is Anna1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111....etc

how do I do it to rename in the following inc

```
Anna
Anna1
Anna2
```

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: yes for the main ID correct, I am talking about the duplicate names inside the separate field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i didn't miss something you can make a stored procedure that iterates throw your rows using cursors to do that as following:

```
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE offset INT;
DECLARE title_urlvalue VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
DECLARE ucur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT
    UPDATE phpfox_photo n 
    JOIN (SELECT title_url, MIN(photo_id) min_id 
    FROM phpfox_photo GROUP BY title_url HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) d
    ON n.title_url = d.title_url AND n.photo_id <> d.min_id;
SET offset = 1;
SET no_more_rows = TRUE;
select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;
OPEN ucur;
uloop: LOOP
  FETCH  ucur
  if counter >= num_rows then
    no_more_rows = False;
  endif
  INTO   title_urlvalue;
  IF no_more_rows THEN
    CLOSE ucur;
    LEAVE uloop;
   END IF;
   update title_urlvalue = Concat(title_urlvalue,offset);
  SET offset = offset + 1;
  SET counter = counter + 1;
END LOOP uloop;
close ucur;
```

Comment: Wow, really complicated, there must be a simple way of doing that, something similar like cetver wrote above, but doest work

Comment: @user974435 it is not complicated but this the only way to iterate through the rows of your mysql table i think it will be more easier to do that in php or it is better to consider using Auto_increment column.

Answer (score 1):

With [User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

```
SET @counter:=0;
SET @title_url:='';
UPDATE phpfox_photo n 
  JOIN (SELECT title_url, MIN(photo_id) min_id
        FROM phpfox_photo
        GROUP BY title_url
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) d
  ON n.title_url = d.title_url AND n.photo_id <> d.min_id
  SET n.title_url = IF(n.title_url <> @title_url, CONCAT(@title_url:=n.title_url, @counter:=1), CONCAT(n.title_url, @counter:=@counter+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use modulo to produce numbering, like this (SQLite example, but should be similar in mysql):

```
SELECT *, (rowid  % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table as t WHERE t.name = table.name ) ) FROM table ORDER BY name
```

All you need is to translate `rowid` and modulo function, both availible in mysql.

Then you can `CONCAT` results as you desire.

Comment: this only displaying all the records ?

Comment: You can use this to fill an extra column and then concat, or with `JOIN`. I've only given you an idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE phpfox_photo n
       JOIN
              (SELECT  title_url,
                       MIN(photo_id) min_id
              FROM     phpfox_photo
              GROUP BY title_url
              HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
              )
              d
       ON     n.title_url = d.title_url
       AND    n.photo_id <> d.min_id
       SET    n.title_url = 
              CASE
                     WHEN <last char is int>
                     THEN <replace last char with incremented last char>
                     ELSE <string + 1>
              END
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<last char is int>
                     THEN <replace last char with incremente' at line 14

Comment: This is not solution. This is algorithm.